# Binding to Properties in a StackPanel doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm building a small Windows 8 app and after hours of banging my head, can't figure out why my Binding isn't working. I have this ViewModel:

```
public class DetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private BookDataService _bookDataService;

    private ObservableCollection<Book> _authorsBooks;
    public ObservableCollection<Book> AuthorsBooks
    {
        get
        {
            return _authorsBooks;
        }
            set
        {
            _authorsBooks = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AuthorsBooks");
        }
    }

    private string _bookTitle;
    public string BookTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _bookTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            _bookTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BookTitle");
        }
    }


    public DetailsViewModel()
    {
        _authorsBooks = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
    }

    public async Task GetBookDetails(string bookID)
    {
        _bookDataService = new BookDataService();
        var remoteResults = await _bookDataService.GetBookDetailsAsync(bookID);

        _bookTitle = remoteResults.Title;
    }

    public async Task GetAuthorBooks(string authorID)
    {
        _bookDataService = new BookDataService();
        var remoteResults = await _bookDataService.GetAuthorBooksAsync(authorID);

        foreach (var book in remoteResults)
            _authorsBooks.Add(book);
    }
}
```

This is the XAML for the StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="BookDetailsStackPanel" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            DataContext="{Binding DetailsViewModel}">
    <Image Source="{Binding LargeImage}" 
           Width="200" Height="300" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
           Margin="24"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Margin="24" Text="{Binding BookTitle}" Foreground="Black"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="24" Text="{Binding Author.Name}" Foreground="Black"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="24" Foreground="Black">
            <Run Text="{Binding Rating}"/>
            <Run Text="("/>
            <Run Text="{Binding RatingsCount}"/>
            <Run Text=")"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I initialize the ViewModel in the code-behind and get the data:

```
private DetailsViewModel _detailsViewModel = new DetailsViewModel();
public DetailsViewModel DetailsViewModel
{
    get { return this._detailsViewModel; }
}

async void DetailsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BookDetailsProgressRing.IsActive = true;
    await _detailsViewModel.GetBookDetails(_bookID);
    BookDetailsProgressRing.IsActive = false;
}
```

Obviously, I'm only talking about the `BookTitle` property, I will set the others once I know what's wrong with my code.

After hours of debugging I can say for sure, that `BookTitle` is set to the correct value, but it just doesn't bind to the `TextBlock`. Also, I have a `ListView` on the same page, that binds to the `AuthorsBooks` property and it works perfectly, so I assume my problem is with the `StackPanel`.

Also, when running the app, there aren't any Binding Errors showing up in the Output window.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You are setting the value to the field `_bookTitle` inside the `GetBookDetails`, not the property right? Obviously, unless you invoke the setter, `PropertyChanged` won't be called.

Comment: Well, I'm using the exact same approach for all the properties on my other pages and it works without a hitch. Why should this one be different ?

Answer (score 1):

I was just stuck on a similar problem - couldn't get a property to change after updating the ObservableCollection. Referring back to the tutorial [Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel pattern in a Windows Phone app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on the Windows Phone dev centre, I added the PropertyChangedEventHandler and a RaisePropertyChanged event to the class and it worked! See below:

```
public class ActivityLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string strLogID { get; set; } //unique id for the log entry.
    private string _strLogDate;
    public string strLogDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _strLogDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _strLogDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("strLogDate");
        }
    }
    public bool booIsUploaded { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Mathew said in the comment you are updating the field `_bookTitle` directly and not via its property setter so the `PropertyChanged` event that suppose to "tell" your text block to update is never raised.

The reason this works in all things related to authors is because of the use of `ObservableCollection`.
Binding works in such a way that an event must be raised, listing the relevant property name, that signals the relevant `UIElement` to update.
In most cases the accrues when we set a new value to the property, that is why it is very common to put the `OnPropertyChanged` call there. But for lists the story is a bit different, because we usually wont to know not only when a new value has been set to the entire list but also when items inside the list has been add or removed. `ObservableCollection` does just that, it raises an event every time an item is add or removed (you could even register to this event if you wont).

Back to your code, now that you know that take a look at the critical different between your Get methods.
`GetBookDetails` updates `_bookTitle` directly and therefore no event is raised and your `TextBlock` has no why to know it need to update is value.
In `GetAuthorBooks` you also address `_authorsBooks` directly but you do not change is value but simply ADDING items, now just like the last case YOUR `OnPropertyChanged` method is never called, but `ObservableCollection` raises it's own event when the item is added therefore telling the relevant `UIElement` to update.

In fact if you only plan to add or remove items from your `ObservableCollection` and not change is value you don't even need to to call `OnPropertyChanged` in the setter, you need this call it only if you replace the current list with a different one.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, I should just set the property in the Get method, not the field ?

`BookTitle = remoteResults.Title;`

If that's all, it still isn't working.

Comment: You said in your original post that you have a working bind between `AuthorsBooks` and a `ListView`.
I see in the xaml that you also have a bind between `Author.Name` and a `TextBlock`, does this bind works or fails?

Comment: Well you be happy to hear that I managed to recreate your problem on my machine and it was solved by removing the `DataContex` bindind from the XAML and setting it manually in the ctor at the code behind like so:

`BookDetailsStackPanel.DataContext = DetailsViewModel;`

What really bothers me right now is that I don't know why this works like this.
I did a quick search and came up empty so I'll have to get back to you on that one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort, but after a couple of days without any progress, I just scraped the whole page and started over. Now it works like a charm, even though I haven't really made any major changes to the code (mainly to the xaml, none to the code-behind), so I also have no idea what the problem was... And at one point, I also tried setting the DataContext manually in the code-behind, but it didn't work for me.